# Can I transform a token copy of a double-faced card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

If I activate my [The Scarab God](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Scarab%20God%5d) on [Jace, Vryn's Prodigy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%5d%2b%5bVryn%27s%5d%2b%5bProdigy%5d) and then flip the token of Jace, do I still get a [Jace, Telepath Unbound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%20Telepath%20Unbound%5d)? And if so, what zone does Jace, Telepath Unbound go to when he dies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot transform a token of [Jace, Vryn's Prodigy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJace%2c%5d%2b%5bVryn%27s%5d%2b%5bProdigy%5d) this way.

> 110.5g A token that has left the battlefield can’t move to another zone or come back onto the battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704.

So any effect that exiles a token and then brings it back will fail to bring it back, and it will cease to exist next time state-based actions are checked.

Note that you cannot transform any token that is copying a double-faced card; but for a different reason. If you have a token copy of [Delver of Secrets](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDelver%20of%20Secrets%5d), and try to transform it, it will also fail.

> 701.27a To transform a permanent, turn it over so that its other face is up. Only permanents represented by double-faced **cards** can transform.
>
> 110.5e A token is subject to anything that affects permanents in general or that affects the token’s card type or subtype. **A token isn’t a card** (even if represented by a card that has a Magic back or that came from a Magic booster pack).

Comment: Agreed I have changed the subject. Thank you for the answer!